# How to capture stdout/stderr/time into variables in Zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Suppose the following function exists.

```
action() {
    sleep 1
    echo 'stdout'
    >&2 echo 'stderr'
}
```

I want to capture each of the following items into shell variables.

- stdout
- stderr
- execution time

The following code does the trick only in Bash.

```
unset stdout stderr time
eval "$(
    { time action >&3 2>&4; } \
    2> >(time=$(cat); typeset -p time) \
    3> >(stdout=$(cat); typeset -p stdout) \
    4> >(stderr=$(cat); typeset -p stderr)
)"

echo "stdout: $stdout"
echo "stderr: $stderr"
echo "time: $time"
```

How can we achieve in Zsh?

Comment: Are you sure the above doesn't work in [tag:zsh]?

Comment: I confirmed that. `$time` gets empty.

Comment: It seems like you're bending over backwards to avoid temporary files.  Why not just use some temp files and move on?  eg `trap 'rm -f $time $err $out' 0; err=$(mktemp); out=$(mktemp); $time=$(mktemp); { time action 2>$err >$out; } 2>$time; ... `

Comment: You're right. Temporary files can handle not only texts but also binaries; it's a certainly general solution. Even so, I wish there were some elegant ways without generating temporarily files...